# Binance search API returns 403 when using with google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, exception, fetch, binance

I'm using the binance API to get the prices of usdt. The API works on postman but it doesn't work on google script.

```
function fetchCryptoPricesFromApi() {
  const data = {
    "page": 1,
    "rows": 10,
    "payTypes": [],
    "asset": "USDT",
    "tradeType": "SELL",
    "fiat": "LKR",
    "publisherType": null,
    "transAmount": "2600"
  }

  const payload = JSON.stringify(data)

  const options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload
  }

  let response;
  
  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', options);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Oops Error, ', error);
    return
  }

  const prices = JSON.parse(response)['data'];
  console.log(prices)
}
```

I get the following error when executing this,

```
Oops Error,  { [Exception: Request failed for https://p2p.binance.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)] name: 'Exception' }
```

I tried waiting some time as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your showing error message, I confirmed the status code `403`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) In this case, it is considered that the site cannot be directly accessed from the Google side. I think that the reason for your issue is due to this.

In this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose access to the URL without directly running the script with the script editor. When I tested this workaround, I confirmed that the value could be returned.

In this workaround, the following flow is used.

1. Put the custom function of `=fetchCryptoPricesFromApi()` to a cell.
2. Retrieve the values from the API.
3. Retrieve the values from the cell.
4. Parse the value as JSON data.

The sample script of this workaround is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this workaround, I use Google Spreadsheet. So please create a new Google Spreadsheet and open the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, copy and paste the following script. And, run `main()` function with the script editor.

```js
function fetchCryptoPricesFromApi() {
  const data = {
    "page": 1,
    "rows": 10,
    "payTypes": [],
    "asset": "USDT",
    "tradeType": "SELL",
    "fiat": "LKR",
    "publisherType": null,
    "transAmount": "2600"
  }
  const payload = JSON.stringify(data)
  const options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": payload
  }
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', options);
  return response.getContentText();
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  range.setFormula("=fetchCryptoPricesFromApi()");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const value = range.getValue();
  range.clearContent();
  const prices = JSON.parse(value)['data'];
  console.log(prices)
}
```

Comment: @A.S. SAMARASINGHE Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.